# Process.Start slow when spawning more new processes

Tags: c#, iis, windows-services, process.start

Processes launched via `Process.Start` seems to have around a 26-second delay when the spawned process (the "child") launches more new processes (the "grandchildren") - I'm trying to find a way to solve this issue.  Specifically, this is occurring when the original process (the "parent") is an ASP.Net website or a Windows Service (tried both).

We're attempting to run a server-side command-line tool to gather information, make modifications in the file system, and continue with other processes when the "child" is finished.  When creating the "child" directly via command-line, there is no delay, and with certain command-line parameters, the "child" does not spawn new processes, and there is no delay.  However, with other parameters, the "child" spawns "grandchildren" (the same executable as itself, but we can't modify its code) and seems to have a 25-30 second (usually 26 seconds) delay before the first process is started, and then runs normally.

I've tried modifying the `UseShellExecute` property, the `CreateNoWindow` property, and the `WindowStyle` property, to no effect.  `ErrorDialog` and the `RedirectStandard*` properties are false.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
using (Process p = new Process())
{
    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(exePath, args)
    {
        WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory,
        UseShellExecute = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
    };
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

Oh, I don't think it matters as I've seen the issue referenced elsewhere (but no solutions), but the exePath I'm using points to msysgit's git.exe.

Comment: Grand children processes? Isn't there a built-in class in the framework that allows you to achieve this functionality to avoid all this spawning?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm launching an exe that we have no control over, and it's choosing to launch its own new processes, or I wouldn't be encountering this issue.

Comment: Another thing that you could check: Is it also slow when you put your code in a command line application and call that?

Comment: I don't believe so, though I'm not sure the server admin booted the command console into the proper user login.  We'll check that, too.

Comment: I'm getting same issue, but while launching a directory. Process.Start("E:") takes around 30 seconds, in a single user, winXpHome system, user account is administrator account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell a reason why this might happen, you need to do further troubleshooting.

I would suggest that you use Process Explorer and Process Monitor to look for potential problems.

I would guess that the problem is not directly in your code but more related to the environment of the user. For example, the w3wp.exe process runs in a non-GUI session (session 0) and the user might not be configured to have web access (proxy configuration) so that you might see a timeout issue here.

Comment: The strange thing is that it actually does resolve after a short period of time.  Process Monitor is a good suggestion - I'll see what's going on and post back with more info.

Comment: Process Monitor was what I needed - the issue wound up being something more appropriately asked on serverfault.  Thanks for your help so long ago.

Comment: Wanted to let you know - our sysadmin finally got it worked out, thanks to info from Process Monitor - it did happen to be a permissions issue, as hspain says.  Now git responds within a second!

Answer (score 2):

I had this same exact problem executing a .bat file which in turn made a call to git.cmd using Process.Start from a windows service.  The git command would execute immediately if the .bat file was ran directly from the command line, but would delay exactly 50 seconds any time it was called from the windows service.

It came down to a permissions issue.  After configuring my windows service to run as a user (administrator in my case), the git process ran immediately.  You can probably modify your service installer to run the service as "User", but you can just modify the service properties after it's installed to the same effect.

There may be ways to enable "Local Service" to get around the delay, but I wouldn't know how.