# Spawing exe not inheriting permissions

Tags: c#, visual-c++, mapi

I have an exe (test.exe) which is a 32 bit written in c++ (unicode charset). This exe will perform the restore operation. The steps include:

1. check outlook installation and load msmapi32.dll
2. create a subfolder in inbox of the specified user.
3. importing eml file into the subfolder.

These operations are done using temporary user who has given full access permission.

This exe is executing fine. The issue is when I try to spawn this exe using C# Process.start(), it fails with `[MAPI_E_FAILONEPROVIDER]` while calling "createstoreentryid".

Any suggestions please.

Comment: The machine is logged in as a domain administrator. Can you explain how to use UNC credentials?

Answer (score 0):

```
       using (UNCAccessWithCredentials unc = new UNCAccessWithCredentials())
        {
            if (unc.NetUseWithCredentials(path,
                                          userName,
                                          domain,
                                          passWord,textFile))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
            }

        }
```

Comment: I don't want to access the share. Mapi needs the permission to logon to other user's mailbox. I tried by creating another c++ console application and spawned the exe successfully. Here the problem is spawning the same exe from C#.

Comment: @inmar ok i understand now did you manage to solve the problem , if not have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513830/process-start-slow-when-spawning-more-new-processes

Comment: Found the issue. Now I'm able to spawn the exe form C# using process.start().
Issue:  C++ exe was using unicode char set. I changed to multicharacter set in prj setting.

Thanks